# Calculating travel time to hospitals via Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: geemap

I was trying to run a script (originally written in the JavaScript language) using the Python API. First, I needed to convert the script from JavaScript to Python. Using the geemap package, I was able to do it with js_to_snippet function. I had some debugging issues and I overcame it but even though I was able to run the script properly, I could not see any result. Here is last code I worked on:

```
import ee
import geemap
Map = geemap.Map()



dataset = ee.Image('Oxford/MAP/accessibility_to_healthcare_2019')
friction = ee.Image('Oxford/MAP/friction_surface_2019')

accessibilityPalette = [
  'F2FEF8', 'DEFCE1', 'C9F3BC', 'CBECA7', 'D6E793','E2D87B', 'D4A561', 
  'C46C49', 'AB3A38', '922F4B', '7D285D', '672069','3A1453', '1B0C3C', 
  '050526', '00030F', '000000'
]
frictionPalette = [
  '313695', '4575B4', '74ADD1', 'ABD9E9', 'E0F3F8','FFFFBF', 'FEE090', 
  'FDAE61', 'F46D43', 'D73027', 'A50026'
]

accessibilityVis = {'min':0, 'max':41556, 'palette':accessibilityPalette}
logAccessibility = dataset.where(dataset.gt(0), dataset.log())
accessibilityRgb = logAccessibility.visualize(**{'bands': ['accessibility']}, **accessibilityVis)

background = ee.Image(0).visualize(**{'palette':['11101E']})
accessibilityBlended = background.blend(accessibilityRgb).updateMask(1)

Map.addLayer(accessibilityBlended, {}, 'Accessibility to Cities 2019')

frictionVis = {'min':0.0022, 'max':0.04, 'palette':frictionPalette}
frictionRgb = friction.visualize(**{'bands': ['friction']}, **frictionVis)

Map.addLayer(frictionRgb, {}, 'Friction Surface', False)
hospitals = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(40.98441, 29.10682)), # Memorial Hastanesi Ataşehir
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(41.00105, 28.88026)), # Memorial HIZMET Hospital, Istanbul
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(40.98376, 28.87284)), # Yaşar Hospital, Bakırköy
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(41.12728, 29.02468)), # Acıbadem Hospital /  Maslak
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(41.05569, 28.99962)), # Acıbadem Hospital / Fulya
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(40.99262, 28.86408)), # Bakırköy Psychiatric Hospital
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(40.99960, 28.91754)), # Balıklı Greek Hospital
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(41.10506, 28.77646)), # Başakşehir Çam and Sakura City Hospital
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(40.99980, 29.20895)), # Sancaktepe Prof. Dr. Feriha Öz Emergency Hospital
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(40.99387, 28.91525)), #Surp Pirgiç Armenian Hospital
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(41.03290, 28.98437)), # Taksim German Hospital
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(40.97060, 28.80847)), # Yeşilköy Prof. Dr. Murat Dilmener Emergency Hospital
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(41.17754, 28.74698)), # Arnavutköy Government Hospital, Arnavutköy
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(41.05094, 28.79650)), # Batı Bahat Hastanesi, İkitelli
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(40.99377, 28.70769)), # Düzey Göz Merkezi Istanbul / Avcilar
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(41.08630, 29.01771)), # Estethica Plastic Surgery Hospital / Levent  
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(40.98513, 29.11006)), # Estethica Plastic Surgery Hospital / Ataşehir
])

hospitalImage = ee.Image().float().paint(hospitals, 1)
hospitalImage = hospitalImage.updateMask(hospitalImage)

travelTime = friction.select(0).cumulativeCost(**{'source': hospitalImage, 'maxDistance':200000})

logTravelTime = travelTime.where(travelTime.gt(0), travelTime.log())
travelTimeRgb = logTravelTime.visualize(**accessibilityVis)

Map.addLayer(logTravelTime, {}, 'Accessibility to Hospitals', False)
```

Any ideas how I can change the code?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. First, take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and check how to ask. Second, you need either `ee.Authenticate()` or `ee.Initialize()`. I recommend you to read carefully [An Intro to the Earth Engine Python API](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/intro-to-python-api)

Comment: Thanks, I will read what you recommended to me. I tried ee.Initialize and ee.Authenticate but nothing changed. The other layers like accessibility and friction datasets are shown on the map but accessibility to hospitals layer is not.

Comment: How did you manage to access data without authentication?

Comment: Hi again. I opened anaconda prompt and activated my conda environment. I run the script in Jupyter notebook. I already had gee account. Is it what you're asking?

Comment: For working with python API, you need to first: import ee. 2nd: authenticate. 3rd: run your code

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I updated geemap package, I added ee.Initialize and it got solved.